# Running $.ajax() Multiple Times

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jQuery $.ajax() function that is returning a base64 value's, which are pdf pages, on success. I have to return multiple base64 values, so the only way that I could think of how to do this, is to loop through the $.ajax() function. When each success is returned, I write the base64 value into an image element. This works fine.  The problem is, because it is asynchronous, it does not necessarily return the pages in order.
I understand that it isn't the best method, but how can I chain this if I am always going to have a different value, which is the page count?

```
    for (i = 1; i <= pdfPageCount; i++) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'Page.aspx/Method',
                 dataType: 'json',
                error: function (err) {
                    alert('Error: ' + err);
                },

                 success: function (resultStr) {
                    //alert('Page: ' + i);

                    var sigImage = document.createElement("img");
                    sigImage.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + 
    resultStr.d);

                    document.getElementById("imgId").appendChild(sigImage);
                },
            });
    } // end the for loop
```

The HTML just has a div:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="imgId">
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: By definition, Ajax is asynchronous. You have probably two solutions: callback hell or promises...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They key is to use [when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). While you can chain your calls in a synchronous manner, I wouldn't suggest it. A better approach would be to asynchronously call for each page, then await all the results simultaneously.

```
var pages = [];
var deferredObjs = [];
for (i = 0; i <= pdfPageCount; i++) {
            deferredObjs[i] = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'Page.aspx/Method',
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (err) {
                alert('Error: ' + err);
            },

             success: function (resultStr) {
             pages[i] = resultStr;
            },
        });
} // end the for loop


$.when.apply( $, deferredObjs ).then( aFunctionToProcessPageResults() );
```

Also, shouldn't your POST be supplying the page number to return? Note that I changed your index variable to start a 0. You may need to account for this.

Comment: I ended up using something very similar to this.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
                url:"url", 
                data:form,
                dataType:'json',
                async:true,
                type:'post',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(data){}
              });
```

async:true

Comment: This does answer the question, but for performance reasons, it isn't desirable to make one request to the server at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recurse through the ajax calls from the success callback as opposed to using iteration.

```
    (function recurse(i){
        if(i > pdfPageCount)return;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'Page.aspx/Method',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (err) {
                alert('Error: ' + err);
            },
            success: function (resultStr) {
                recurse(i+1);

                var sigImage = document.createElement("img");
                sigImage.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + 
resultStr.d);

                document.getElementById("imgId").appendChild(sigImage);
            }
        });
    })(1)
```